# How find out who is the owner of a program?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, setuid

I'm studing Set-UID Privileged Programs, and it seems that a program executes with a its own owner privilegies.
Example: passwd can read/write the shadow file because it belongs to a root user. How can i find this kind of information for other programs?

Answer (score 0):

Use [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html), `geteuid(2)`, [getresuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getresuid.2.html) and the corresponding [setuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html), [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html) appropriately. See also [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & carefully [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Read about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Read the [Setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) wikipage. A process running a setuid executable can call `seteuid` to gain privilege.

Comment: My problem is somthing like this:

Run Set-UID shell programs in Linux, and describe and explain your observations. (a) Login as root, copy /bin/zsh to /tmp, and make it a set-root-uid program with permission 4755. Then login as a normal user, and run /tmp/zsh. Will you get root privilege? Please describe your observation.

If I moved as a root, it means that the program has roots privilegies, rigth? But Im looking for a way to prove it!

Comment: If you are `root` you can do stuff like `mkdir /hacked` which regular users cannot. (Remember to clean up after yourself.)

Comment: The `/tmp` filesystem is however often mounted so that the setuid bit on binaries is not respected there. This is a security feature to disable precisely this sort of hack. `mount | grep nosuid`

Answer (score 0):

When you set user identification (the 4755 mode) permission to an executable file, a process that runs this file is granted access based on the owner of the file.

In this case you copy /bin/zsh as root user and then set the 4755 mode, /tmp/zsh so will give root privileges to the user that will run the file rather than user privileges.

This special permission allows a user to access files and directories that are normally only available to the owner.

Have you tried to make what you have been asked?

Comment: My try is something like that: i used a root user to copy the file (zsh), and i tried to execute as a normal user. So, i did a program, that executes a command (in this example, a passwd command). My idea, if this command is running as root, i could change an other users password. A root user can do that, so if I can do that as a normal user running this script, it's a obvious break of security. But... there's no way do that. I tried to make a root user as a owner of this program, but i can't execute this properly as a normal user (with no root privilegies).